# Getting URL for twitter,Facebook,Gmail from desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, twitter, gmail

we need to Login Facebook,Twitter,Gmail from our desktop application we have

OAuth tokens such as
1.Consumer key,
2.Consumer Secret,
3.Token,
4.Token secret.

We have these detail.. And In our desktop application we embedded Web browser.. So we need to open the Facebook,Twitter,Gmail in the embedded web browser(Without asking Login Credentials) from our desktop app..

We need a URL that automatically login to specified application(Twitter,Facebook..etc) in **Browser**

Comment: How to get URL for Browser which automtically login to the specified app (Facebook,Twitter, etc) through OAuth by passing generated Credenials(Conumerkey,consumer screeet,Token,Token secret)

Comment: Can you specify link for documentation of twitter for getting the URL ?

Comment: ...you want someone to tell you where to find the documentation? Have you even tried twitter.com or google?  This is a site for solving programming questions, not helping you google

Comment: the All goole links are showing only How to get the OAUTH tokens..                 https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature

Comment: So We need After getting that How can we get the Link to Opened in Browser..  We already tried GetAuthotisationLink() and GetAuthundicationLink in TwitterOAuth object.. but it is throwing Twiter Api Exception..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7796/discussion-between-dinesh-and-kieren-johnstone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

Pretty much the whole point of OAuth is to provide the Consumer (your app) with credentials which can be used to authenticate/authorise API calls to the Service Provider (Facebook) but which cannot be used to log in to the Service Provider website.

What you want to do would destroy this benefit that OAuth has over the [password anti-pattern](http://blog.dave.org.uk/2008/07/password-antipattern.html).